# Share result of Query between separate Jobs in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have the following SQL queries:

- SQL query which DECLARES the some Variables ("declaration query")
- Several SQL Queries to RETRIEVE the data from the BigQuery which are executed separately ("data retreiving queries")
- Each "data retrieving query" depends on the Declared variables
- The values for the Declared variables are changed upon each app's session

The Question is:
is it possible to save the result of "declaration query" (Declared variables) so that the "data retrieving queries" can "see" these variables? To avoid the execution of "declaration query" each time before the each "data retreiving query" runs

Thanks!

I read the BigQuery docs and found that it's possible to use Saved queries, but in my case
the Query to save is not an static query where query params are the SAME all the times.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery does support scripting:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language

Once you get some proficiency in scripting, you can do more get done with stored procedures:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/procedures

You can parameterize, you can save results in temp variables temp tables etc.

Its fun, check it out.

(Going further if you need to create workflows out of it you can always look into https://airflow.apache.org/ or if you are looking for no programming workflow creation option you can look into https://potens.io/products/#magnus )